# Building UDP packet in Python

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, raw-sockets

There's already a code in the internet which shows how to build and send a TCP packet in Python using raw sockets, but I desperately need an example of how building a UDP one.

I read this link http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc768.txt and understands that udp header consists only of src ip, src port, length and checksum, and also read that if I create an IPPROTO_UDP socket instead of IPPROTO_RAW socket, the IP header should be filled automatically by the kernel.

Yet, I had no success in doing such.

Here's the code building tcp packets with raw socket:

```
import socket
import struct

def make_ip(proto, srcip, dstip, ident=54321):
    saddr = socket.inet_aton(srcip)
    daddr = socket.inet_aton(dstip)
    ihl_ver = (4 << 4) | 5
    return struct.pack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , 
                       ihl_ver, 0, 0, ident, 0, 255, proto, 0, saddr, daddr)

def make_tcp(srcport, dstport, payload, seq=123, ackseq=0,
             fin=False, syn=True, rst=False, psh=False, ack=False, urg=False,
             window=5840):
    offset_res = (5 << 4) | 0
    flags = (fin | (syn << 1) | (rst << 2) | 
             (psh <<3) | (ack << 4) | (urg << 5))
    return struct.pack('!HHLLBBHHH', 
                       srcport, dstport, seq, ackseq, offset_res, 
                       flags, window, 0, 0)

srcip = dstip = '127.0.0.1'
srcport, dstport = 11001, 11000
payload = '[TESTING]\n'

ip = make_ip(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, srcip, dstip)
tcp = make_tcp(srcport, dstport, payload)
packet = ip + tcp + payload

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
s.sendto(packet, (dstip, 0))
response, addr = s.recvfrom(65535)
response_id = struct.unpack('!H', response[4:6])
print response_id
```

How to make the same thing with UDP instead?

Best solution for me is just editing the existing code, since reading abstract information didn't help me much.

I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows XP.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

Just this:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((IP,PORT))
```

To send:

```
sock.sendto(message,(IP,PORT))
```

To receive:

```
sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

The 1024 displays the buffer size. There are not other changes necessary as far as the socket part

Comment: I wish to use raw socket in order to read the IP_ID from the packet.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was helpful in making a DNS caching resolver!

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. He explicitly asked about raw UDP packets. This is unfortunately too high level an approach for his question.